# I Know this prints out ip and username but could somebody break this down for me, very simply, thanks! unix

Tags: users

I know this prints out IP and username but could somebody break this down for me, very simply, thanks! unix

```
w -hs|awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n",$1,$3}'
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Try helping yourself: Read `man w` to know more about the program `w` and its flags. `awk` is a bit more complicated, it has its own programming language (which is documented in `man awk` - look for `printf` in there).

Answer (score 0):

`w -hs` - this prints who is logged into the system, but is using **-hs** flags to make the output more clean

then the result of `w -hs` is piped to `awk` which is using `printf` to format the output.

`%s` is a format specifier and `\t` means TAB. `\n` stands for NEWLINE. And after these, we have `$1` and `$3`. So this whole thing `awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n",$1,$3}'` means print the first and third string from the output, place a tab between them and print the result on a newline

For me, this would be the same as using `awk '{print $1, "", $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it down:

Note first the "pipe" symbol `|`. This tells us that this is a *two-part* command: the *output* of the first command `w -hs` is "piped" to the second command `awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n",$1,$3}'` for further processing.

The first command `w -hs` outputs information on who is logged into the system (see `man w` for details). In this case, two options, `-h` and `-s`, are added to format the output. See the `COMMAND-LINE OPTIONS` section in `man w` for details. Better, type this command into your terminal, and inspect it.

The output of `w -hs` is "piped" to `awk`, meaning that `awk` will operate on the output of `w -hs`.

`awk` is a language typically used for text processing; see `man awk` for details, or one of the countless `awk` tutorials on the Internet to learn more. `awk` code is rather *dense*, and understanding it may require some study.

The **expression** `'{printf "%s\t%s\n",$1,$3}'` tells `awk` how to process the data piped to it from `w -hs`. In summary, these instructions are:

*Using `printf`, print the values from fields (or columns) 1 and 3 (`$1,$3`) as "strings" (`%s`) separated by a tab (`\t`), and then add a "newline" (`\n`) at the end.*

Please note that this is a brief summary of `awk`, and omits many important details. If your interest, or your job description, demand a more detailed understanding of `awk`, please refer to a wide variety of resources online, or in hardcopy.